# Custom post type clashes with external JS library

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

My website uses a JS booking script (widget) that uses the GET parameter "accommodation" to tell the booking page which accommodation it likes to book.

However, I have a custom post type with that exact name:

```
register_post_type('accommodation', [
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-location-alt',
        'supports' => ['title', 'revisions'],
        'has_archive' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'rewrite' => [
                'slug' => 'our-accommodations',
                'with_front' => false,
                'feeds' => false,
                'pages' => false,
        ],
    ]);
```

and it breaks the external JS script **unless** I set `publicly_queryable` of that custom post type to `false`.

How to solve this without changing the name of the post type?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `query_var` argument in the args array when you call `register_post_type`. That way you can have "accommodation" as a post type and the querystring variable could be something like "our-accommodations". See [register_post_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters)

```
register_post_type('accommodation', [
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-location-alt',
        'supports' => ['title', 'revisions'],
        'has_archive' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => 'our-accommodations',
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this makes all links of the post type go to `https://example.com/archives/accommodation/{name}` which returns a 404.